# Do household air purifiers prevent illness?

Tags: environmental-health, technology

[Air purifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_purifier) that use glass-fiber HEPA material are said to reduce contaminant in the air that can cause illness, including cold and flu viruses, cigarette smoke.

One example is, [Are Air Purifiers Beneficial for Good health? << Air Purifier Reviews, Guides and Ratings](http://www.airpurifierreviews.com/are-air-purifiers-beneficial-for-good-health/):

> - These days, the air we breathe is dirtier and more polluted than ever before. After all, the factors that have contributed to global
>     warming are of course destructive to the environment, but can also be
>     **hazardous to the health of everyday people**. [...] One of the most
>     important things one can do to improve their air quality is to use an
>     air purifier.
> - Since **many of the common illnesses (cold, flu) are airborne**, improving the quality of the air you live in can ultimately lower the
>     chances of getting sick.
> - There are many silent, invisible contaminants floating around the air that most people don’t even think about. The fact is, they can be
>     harmful, especially if one lives amongst them. Household contaminants
>     are extremely common, and avoiding them can be impossible without an
>     air purifier. Common household contaminants include cigarette smoke,
>     dust, aerosols and pet dander/odors.
> - While household contaminants are certainly one of the main reasons to use an air purifier, they are equally useful in eliminating harmful
>     microorganisms that float through the air. **Mold, pathogens and viruses
>     are all airborne hazards** that many people come into contact with on a
>     daily basis. Continual exposure to these and other hazards can have a
>     very negative affect on one’s health, which is why it is wise to take
>     any and all necessary measures to ensure that your air is as clean as
>     it could possibly be.

(I am excluding any improvements in reducing allergens, such as pet dander, which presumably only affect people with specific allergies, and special cases such as industrial/construction
 settings.)

Is there scientific evidence that air purifiers reduce the risk of illness?

Comment: purifying the air of asbestos dust would definitely be beneficial

Comment: The first of the two references which you cited starts with, "If you are someone who’s sensitive to contaminants found in the air": which is not what you want to ask about, because you want to ask about "normally healthy people without allergies". Therefore I edited your question to remove that first reference and to emphasize (quote from) the second reference.

Comment: This question was asked before, with some good answers: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7407/do-air-purifiers-do-what-they-are-supposed-to-do

Comment: Note that the other question is specifically referring to allergens, so it *is* concerning people with allergic reactions to certain things.